# SQLite: How to display only column names which have null fields

Tags: sqlite

SQLite:

How to display only column names for null fields in SQLite?

```
             TABLE_DEMO
```

---

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Drinks | Null | Null |
| 2 | Null | Food | Travel |
| 3 | Null | Null | Fish |

Required Output

---

| ID | Null Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Column B |
| 1 | Column C |
| 2 | Column A |
| 3 | Column A |
| 3 | Column B |

Tried using Case but it was outputting in a single line as comma separated values. Need the column names to be to be in separate rows.

---

| ID | Null Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Column B, Column C |
| 2 | Column A |
| 3 | Column A, Column B |

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID, 'Column A' AS `Null Column` FROM tablename WHERE `Column A` IS NULL
UNION ALL  
SELECT ID, 'Column B' FROM tablename WHERE `Column B` IS NULL
UNION ALL  
SELECT ID, 'Column C' FROM tablename WHERE `Column C` IS NULL
ORDER BY ID, `Null Column`;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XJ8es535).

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, after trying this solution, I found out that the UNION ALL approach is slowing down the database's performance drastically, when the table data is too large. Is there any way we can do this faster?